# jquery greybox pass query string

Tags: jquery, asp.net

```
 <a href="../../AddLesson.aspx?id=<%# Request.QueryString["id"] %>" rel="gb_page_center[340, 380]"><img src="../../images/add_lesson_icon.png" width="17" height="18" alt="Add Lesson" /></a>
```

Here is my code to open a greybox popup by clicking on anchor tag and i also want to send data through querystring. i have done like above. but it is not working.
Any help

Answer (score 0):

Instead of this:

```
<%# Request.QueryString["id"] %>
```

Try this instead:

```
<%= Request.QueryString["id"] %>
```